# Why I need JavaScript prototype in extending object?

Tags: javascript, oop

Long time I write code in JavaScript, using jQuery, ReactJS and NodeJS server side (ExpressJS). I learned partially MDN and other sources, however there is one question I can not found an answer for.
Why follow code requires `prototype` object's property? Why I can not use `forEach` directly from `Array` object? I mean, in terms of OOP, if `Array` class extends class contains `forEach` method, I can call it from object instantiated from `Array` directly, I don't need, using reflection find base class, instantiate it and call the method from the base class.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', someFunction);
});
```

Example taken from here: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/

Comment: Older browsers did not have forEach on DOM elements, in fact I think IE11 didn't even have forEach on DOM elements..  ps. DOM elements are not arrays..

Comment: `querySelectorAll` doesn't return an array.  It returns an array-like object, a NodeList.

Comment: And if I use exactly Array as first parameter for `call`, I can ommit the `prototype`?

Comment: No - the first param to `call` needs to be the nodeset you wish to iterate over.

Comment: Don't bother with that code, it's outdated. You'd write `for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('.klasses')) el.addEventListener('click', someFunction);` today.

Comment: For IE's lack of `forEach` you can also do -> `if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {  NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;}` to act as a polyFill,..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', someFunction);
});
```

could indeed be written as

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', someFunction);
});
```

Going through the Array prototype object is just a way to access the functions available to any array instance without having to actually create an array. Using one or the other is mostly a matter of preference, and though the second form does involve the creation of an array object, the performance implications are minimal.

Comment: Create a new Array? serius?

Comment: @Ele I don't understand your question; `[]` creates a new array, yes, if that's what you are asking.\

Comment: It's entirely possible that a modern JavaScript runtime would be able to skip the instantiation of that array, or at least it's conceivable.

Comment: Yes, create a new array is not a good practice just to get access to that function.

Comment: So, as I see, `prototype` i similar to accessing method in static way or instantiating the object and access it method. OK, Thanx.

Comment: @Ele why is it "not a good practice"?  What are the disadvantages? Personally I think it's a little clearer; it's shorter and easier to read.

Comment: **Disadvantages:** Like I've mentioned, *create a new array just to get access to that function `forEach`*.

Comment: The performance impact will be completely negligible. JavaScript is extremely good at creating objects. And because the array is never referenced, it's (at least conceptually) possible for the optimizer to skip the instantiation anyway.

Comment: I don't see anything "bad" about it though.

Answer (score 1):

> Why I can not use forEach directly from Array object?

The Array object is a constructor function used to create arrays. It doesn't have a `forEach` property of its own.

You can access the `forEach` property either from an instance of Array (which you can create with `new Array` or, more idiomatically, with `[]`), or by accessing the `prototype` that gets applied to instances of Array.

Comment: Actually it does seem to, at least in Firefox. `Array.forEach` gives "function forEach()". Not that it seems to be usable; `Array.forEach.call(['a'], function(g) { alert(g); });` errors.

Comment: @Utkanos [Those are deprecated](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/non-standard-array-string-generics-have-been-deprecated/), they could be used as `Array.forEach(['a'], function(g) { alert(g); });`

Comment: Aha, interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll` doesn't return an Array, returns a `NodeList` (like array-object) instead.  The NodeList has a property called `.length` that indicates the count of elements inside of it.

Some browsers/engines/backend techs are incompatible because that `NodeList` no necessarally will provide the function `forEach`.

So, an alternative is converting that `NodeList` to an Array using the Array prototype:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'), function(el){...})
```

Or, you can use the function `Array.from` that will use the property `.length` to create the array:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.klasses'));
```

### From MDN docs

> Although NodeList is not an Array, it is possible to iterate on it using `forEach()`.  Several older browsers have not implemented this method yet. You can also convert it to an Array using `Array.from`.